# Is OR gives better performance than IN for HIVE queries

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have following two queries in Hive to get some specific result.

```
select * from table1 where col1 IN (a, b, c)
select * from table1 where col1=a OR col1=b OR col1=c
```

As per my understanding **IN** will be converted internally to sequence of **OR**s.
Executed locally in spark-sql but did not find any sort of performance difference(like execution timing,filtered data scanning etc).
So what difference we can see in IN and OR based on the functionality.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Col1 in (a,b,c) is a macro that expands to Col1=a or Col1=b or Col1=c.
```

There is no performance difference

Comment: This would be more valuable if you provided a reference (source, documentation).